# Inserting value from one table into another in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert value of primary key of a table to the foreign key in another table in SQL Server.

Please help me out..

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you have trouble? Are you getting an error - if so: what is it??

Answer (score 6):

```
Insert Into FKTable (FKValue)
Select PKValue
From PKTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
INSERT california_authors (au_id, au_lname, au_fname)
SELECT au_id, au_lname, au_fname
FROM authors
WHERE State = 'CA'
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT PrimaryKey
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable